# How to find out which file upload input a file came from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

In my Action Method I am currently passing 3 files as separate HttpPostedFileBase objects. I'd like to pass them as an IEnumerable container but how could I find out which upload control they came from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand what you mean without your code, but...

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file1, HttpPostedFileBase file2, HttpPostedFileBase file3) {
```

On your method receiving the post whereby file1, 2, 3 etc. are the names of the fields on the client side, would give you that information.

Please provide more information if the above is not what you need.

Comment: No you are right, doing that way does give me the information since MVC maps the parameter names. That's how I'm doing it now. What I'd like to do is pass them as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files  so I can loop through them. If I did that, how would I know which input control the file came from? For example, if they choose not to upload all 3 files and only 1 or 2? In that case, I would need to know which ones they uploaded.

Comment: In your view you would need to reference the file inputs names as files[0], files[1], files[2], etc. The modelbinder happily throws them all into an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` and the order is the order you specified, i.e. the first is the one with name "files[0]".

Comment: You could certainly do that by having the collection in your model and iterating out an editor template in the view. On the controller side, when it comes through you can change the parameter to be a list of files, you'll be able to get the index of the item to tell which ones are populated or not as the case may be.

Comment: Ok, so if one of the fileuploads isn't used, will it just be null in the collection or will it not exist at all?